# index error : list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make an application that matches the user input one by one, and display the percentage of which sentence it belongs to (pre defined sentences)

```
store_word=""
def client_query_function():
    point =0 
    i=0
    z=0 #tells the index number of the sentence
    p=""
    global store_word
    client_query = raw_input(">> ")
    len_client_query=len(client_query)
    i=len_client_query
    for z in range(i):  
        #print client_query[z]
        if  client_query[z]!=" ":
                p=p+client_query[z]     
                store_word=""   
        else:
            store_word=p
            print "store_word" ,store_word

            #dictonary search

timeis =[]
dateis = []

client_query_function()

def timeis_funct(store_word):   
    global pm_timeis    
    timeis[5]=["what","is","the","time","?",""]
    for i in range (len(timeis)):
        if store_word==timeis[i]:
            pm_timeis=pm_timeis+1
        else:
            continue
    return pm_timeis

def dateis_funct(store_word):   
    global pm_dateis    
    dateis[5]=["what","is","the","date","?",""]
    for i in range (len(dateis)):
        if store_word==dateis[i]:
            pm_dateis=pm_dateis+1
        else:
            continue
    return pm_dateis


def percent_cal():
    timeis_funct(store_word)
    dateis_funct(store_word)
percent_cal()
```

while running the program its shows list assignment index out of range, which should not happen

Comment: Provide more information on the error that occurs. In which line does it happen?

Comment: I assume the error happens at the "timeis[5]=["what","is","the","time","?",""]" line, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
timeis[5]=["what","is","the","time","?",""]
```

This is not the correct way to create a list named `timeis` with five elements. The indexing on the left hand side is unnecessary. Try:

```
timeis=["what","is","the","time","?",""]
```

And the same for `dateis[5]=["what","is","the","date","?",""]`.

---

Also, you're going to get `NameError: global name 'pm_timeis' is not defined` because you never declare a variable by that name before you use it inside the function. The `global` statement doesn't create the variable if it doesn't already exist; you still need to do that yourself. You'll need to add

```
pm_timeis=0
pm_dateis=0
```

Somewhere in your code before you call `timeis_funct` and `dateis_funct`.